# Proposed canonical question: Why is it considered bad practice to run everything on the same server?

Tags: discussion, canonical

My usual reaction after seeing questions like [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/1064576/windows-server-vpn-access) is to cry a lot, vote to close and add a suggestion to rethink what you are doing and/or call in a professional.

But I think we can do better than this; we can have a canonical question actually *explaining* why this is so bad in so many ways.

I suggest something like this:

> > This is a [Canonical Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1064576/windows-server-vpn-access) about running too many different things on the same server.
>
> I need to run multiple different services, but I only have (or can afford) a single machine; thus I'll just run everything on it.
>
> Why is this considered bad practice?

Answers should describe why this is generally bad for security, performance, manageability and from an overall design perspective; additional answers can explain why certain services (such as Windows Domain Controllers) should really *not* be colocated with anything else, or why hypervisors should only be used to run virtual machines.

Is this a good idea?

How can the question text be improved?

And also, how should such a question be tagged?

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea as it’s a bit like the canonical question we have for licensing question, but this one would be more specific to design question.

It’s better for the asker to use such canonical than to close as to broad IMO

For the answer I would write under a Windows’s section some facts; like;

- The licensing mode of Microsoft that allow two VM for one Hypervisor for the Standard license. A lot of new comers don’t know that fact and they still try to do all-in-one approch when they have one physical server.
- To give RDS access to a DC it imply more elevated security context for the user right that login.
- Windows Server Essential is an option.
- etc..

For Linux system I would let others weight in of what we can write if it apply.